# How to get the node status?

Tags: nodes

I have a function that returns sets of variables. Now, I want to control the return value by using node status. Basically I dont want the value to be returned when the node is unpublished. Any idea? Here is the function by the way. I just need to add a condition in the return value like this `if($node->status == 1){ return $omniture_variables; }`

```
function my_module_omniture_variables() {
  $current_day = date('D');
  $current_hour = date('G');
  .....

  $omniture_variables['variables'] = array(
    ....
  );

  //Sets omniture variables
  if(module_exists('omniture')) {
  ....
  }
  
  if(count($extra_variables) > 0) {
    $omniture_variables['variables'] = array_merge($omniture_variables['variables'], $extra_variables);
  }

  return $omniture_variables;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid a node_load() you can do:

```
  $query = db_query("SELECT * FROM {node} WHERE nid = %d LIMIT 1", $number);
  $result = db_fetch_object($query);
```

and then look at $result->status.

Comment: any idea why $result->status has no value...cause I'm expecting it to be 0 or 1..any hint?

Comment: ...is the code above applicable to every node the page is loading? I'm so clueless how drupal works regarding this...

Comment: this will work on any node in the system, but you do have to pass it the nid of the node you want to check...that's the $number variable up there...so no, it has no clues what nodes you've loaded already...

Answer (score 8):

Getting a node's status is quite simple:

```
// Get the node with node ID 123.
$node = node_load(123);
// Get its status.
$status = $node->status;
```

That said... I don't know what your function looks like or in which context it's running, so depending on your situation, there may be an even better way to get what you want.

Comment: @marc..is there a way to avoid noad_load()...the reason we are avoiding noad_load is for performance issue...

Comment: Here is my function...
    function my_module_omniture_variables() {
  $current_day = date('D');
  $current_hour = date('G');
  .....

  $omniture_variables['variables'] = array(
    ....
  );

  //Sets omniture variables
  if(module_exists('omniture')) {
  ....
  }
  
  if(count($extra_variables) > 0) {
    $omniture_variables['variables'] = array_merge($omniture_variables['variables'], $extra_variables);
  }

  return $omniture_variables;
    }

Comment: If performance is very important, check out jimajamma's answer. I'm not sure how much faster it is, but it must make a difference, especially if you're doing it for a large number of nodes. In case you're loading a node that has already been loaded during the current request, then you can safely use node_load, because it keeps the node in static cache.

Answer (score 8):

For Drupal 8:

```
<?php

// Get status method
$status = $node->isPublished();

// Set status
node->setPublished(TRUE);
```

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21src%21Entity%21Node.php/function/Node%3A%3AisPublished/8.2.x

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21src%21Entity%21Node.php/function/Node%3A%3AsetPublished/8.2.x

Answer (score 2):

**Drupal 8 method for avoiding using node_load:**

```
$bundle = $node->bundle(); // or $bundle='my_bundle_type';
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node');
$query->condition('status', 1);
$query->condition('type', $bundle); // Optional
$entity_ids = $query->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Drupal 7 Database API](https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/database), you can get the status of a node to determine if it is published or not like this:

```
// Determine if the node is published or not.
$query = db_select('node', 'n')
  ->fields('n', array('status'))
  ->condition('n.nid', $nid)
  ->execute();
$result = $query->fetchObject();
$is_published = $result ? $result->status : FALSE;

if ($is_published) {
  // Take action...
}
else {
  // Relax...
}
```